# SUBSTR CASE MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

| Fruits & Vegetables |
| --- |
| 3 Apples |
| 2 Oranges |
| Cucumber |

I need to extract a the first letter of the string using a substring and a case in mysql:
i.e. I need to extract 3, 2 & C

- where if 3 then "Fruit"
- where if 2 then "Fruit"
- where if C then "Vegetable"

So I have used the following:

```
Type varchar(80)
AS
(case
    when SUBSTR('Fruits & Vegetables',1) = '3' then "Fruit"
when SUBSTR('Fruits & Vegetables',1) = '2' then "Fruit"
when SUBSTR('Fruits & Vegetables',1) = 'C' then "Vegetable"
else NULL
end),
```

what I get is Null as a result can someone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: if Fruits & Vegetables is a column name then it should be enclosed in backticks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: @P.Salmon, I believe that's what's already present 'Fruits & Vegetables'

Comment: Hmm looks like single quotes to me and substr needs  3 arguments  eg SUBSTR(`Fruits & Vegetables`,1,1) = '3' https://dbfiddle.uk/oQGOWblG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

`SUBSTR(fruits_and_vegetables, 1, 1)`

```
SELECT 
(case when SUBSTR(fruits_and_vegetables, 1, 1) = '3' then "Fruit" 
when SUBSTR(fruits_and_vegetables,1,1) = '2' then "Fruit" 
when SUBSTR(fruits_and_vegetables,1,1) = 'C' then "Vegetable" 
else NULL END) as `Fruits & Vegetables` FROM `table_name`
```

Comment: Yes, exactly that was the problem - thanks